# best way to set this angular select menu to change on click

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

Todo:

- select 0 hr only show 15, 30, 45 minutes
- select 1,2,3,4 hr show 0,    15, 30, 45 minutes

How to pass in the array minuteOptionsNoZero when the hour value is selected at 0, or is there another way?

here is the angular form

```
    <div class="row form-inline">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center" [formGroup]="durationForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Hours</label>
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="hours">
        <option [value]="hour.value" *ngFor="let hour of hourOptions">{{ hour.display }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Minutes</label>
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="minutes">
        <option [value]="minute.value" *ngFor="let minute of minuteOptions">{{ minute.display }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button [disabled]="durationForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-success-v2" (click)="onClickSubmit()">
        <strong>SUBMIT</strong>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

typescript file

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.hourOptions = [
  { value: 0, display: '0' },
  { value: 1, display: '1' },
  { value: 2, display: '2' },
  { value: 3, display: '3' },
  { value: 4, display: '4' },
];
this.minuteOptions = [
  { value: 0, display: '00' },
  { value: 15, display: '15' },
  { value: 30, display: '30' },
  { value: 45, display: '45' },
];
this.minuteOptionsNoZero = [
  { value: 15, display: '15' },
  { value: 30, display: '30' },
  { value: 45, display: '45' },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare the variables as `const`.

```js
export const MINUTE_OPTIONS: any[] = [
  { value: 0, display: '00' },
  { value: 15, display: '15' },
  { value: 30, display: '30' },
  { value: 45, display: '45' },
];

export const MINUTE_OPTIONS_NO_ZERO: any[] = [
  { value: 15, display: '15' },
  { value: 30, display: '30' },
  { value: 45, display: '45' },
];
```

2. Create a `Subscription` variable called `subscription`.
3. Subscribe to the value change event of form control `hours`. Perform the assigning value to `minuteOptions` based on the selected `hours` value.
4. Implement `ngOnDestroy` method for unsubscribing the Subscription before the component is destroyed for better performance. Refer to [Cleaning up on instance destruction](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#cleaning-up-on-instance-destruction).

```js
export class AppComponent {
  ...

  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    ...

    this.subscription = this.durationForm.controls.hours.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value) => {
        if (value == 0) this.minuteOptions = MINUTE_OPTIONS_NO_ZERO;
        else this.minuteOptions = MINUTE_OPTIONS;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yd11x6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)